# Why do comments usually get removed from Questions?

Tags: support, migration, comments

For what reasons do comments usually get removed from questions?

[What is meant by channel id > 100 in 802.11?](https://superuser.com/questions/281434/what-is-meant-by-channel-id-100-in-802-11)

I just disagree with this question being moved from Security.SE to Super User.  Doesn't really strike me as a valid reason to remove the comments.

Asking for something to not be moved seems like a good enough reason to not move it.  So long as it is not way off topic and of value to that site.

Comment: `Asking for something to not be moved seems like a good enough reason to not move it.` - sorry, but **no** to this! I can't comment on what is on-topic or not on Security.SE, as I'm not a user of that site (FYI, if you want that discussion you'll need to take it to their meta, obviously), but if something is off-topic where it is posted it should always be migrated or closed - regardless of who asks for it to stay.

Comment: @DMA57361 I clarified that a bit.  Some SE sites have a fundamental flaw where things that are actually on-Topic are judged secretly "Off-topic" because there is another site with an overlapping subject.  Regardless of if is actually is relevant to the user and  to the value of that site. but I guess I am the kind of off topic...

Comment: quite, and I agree (in the past we've had similar issues with people trying to migrate away Linux, Ubuntu and Apple stuff that was perfectly valid here, for example). **However**, (and again I don't use Security.SE so you'd have to ask them to be entirely sure) the question *isn't* about security issues - it's `"Is a Wifi channel of >100 valid?"` - so I'm fairly sure it's off-topic over there...

Comment: Networking questions have always gotten tossed around.  I called it on topic because it is "indirectly" on topic and because of the purpose behind the main subject.  Its not about protecting assets or whatever but it is a question that is relevant to someone who is doing network security.  You can't exclude understanding protocols from IT security.  Its like excluding wget, or kernel questions from Ubuntu.SE.  Remember a user asked this that wanted an answer from the security community, Not SU.

Comment: @DMA57261 Seriously,  if SU wasn't catch all place for homeless questions this would be even more off topic on SU IMHO. What does a basic network protocol question like this have anything to do with end users.  This is what server fault was originally for if it wasn't for the mass SU people spamming SF.  but here I am ranting again at 2 in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

Your comments are noise and somewhat pointless as the moderators have chosen to leave the post on Super User for now.  If you want to discuss it further, the correct place to raise the issue is here on Meta Super User.

Comments are primarily meant for clarification and information directly relating to the question. When comments get derailed and there are 10+ comments on the post just arguing about where it belongs, then they become noise, and the discussion should be carried out on Meta, not polluting the question.

Comment: meta is just too far away sometimes.  I did intend to stop at one comment.  Although just asking would have been nicer.

Comment: @WalterJ89: Too far away? Really? I don't think that one click away is too far away. And what do you mean by "just asking"? Just asking you if it needs to be moved? Why? If the mods think it should be moved, it'll be moved. The original asker shouldn't have much say in it unless it was completely incorrect to move it.

Comment: @Mark Commenting is once mouse click and its even on the same page.  Meta is logging into that site, 2 clicks, copying a link, writing a question and then still leaving a comment saying something it is on meta.  Relatively that is a huge difference.   Just because it can be moved doesn't mean it should be.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what studiohack mentioned:  The comments I remove most of the time are from migrated questions from other sites.  "Belongs on..." type of comments will be cleaned up as well as things that have nothing to do with the question.  I will read through everything on the question/answer and all the comments involved before I make any clean up decision to make sure it does not take away from the readability of the post and comment sequence.

We occasionally have to step in when a couple users get into heated discussion, but it is not very common.  We try to leave as much content as possible on the site, but we want to keep things clean and on-topic.